# no each method on query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the index action of my application, I wish to have listed only the surveys created by the currently logged in user, so instead of doing

```
@surveys = Survey.all
```

I did

```
@mysurveys = Survey.find_by_twitteruser_id(session[:twitteruser_id])
```

However, in displaying the surveys, whereas with the @surveys = Survey.all, I can do

```
<% for survey in @surveys %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= survey.name %></td>
      <td><%= survey.twitteruser_id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Show", survey %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_survey_path(survey) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", survey, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

if I try that with @mysurveys, I get an error that it doesn't have the method 'each.'

I did an inspect on both @surveys and @mysurveys in the logs, and it turns out they are not the same. @surveys is an array

```
[#<Survey id: 32, name: "Mike", twitteruser_id: 1, created_at: "2013-02-18 21:15:18", updated_at: "2013-02-18 21:15:18">]
```

and @mysurvey is I-don't-know-what but it doesn't have the array brackets and therefore I assume that's the reason it doesn't have 'each' method

```
#<Survey id: 32, name: "Mike", twitteruser_id: 1, created_at: "2013-02-18 21:15:18", updated_at: "2013-02-18 21:15:18">
```

I tried to do @mysurvey.to_a but it didn't work.

Can you help me out here with a bit of an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find_by methods return a single result by adding LIMIT 1 to the query, you want to use find_all_by method

```
@mysurveys = Survey.find_all_by_twitteruser_id(session[:twitteruser_id])
```

or better yet since these methods will be deprecated in Rails 4

```
@mysurveys = Survey.where(:twitteruser_id => session[:twitteruser_id])
```

or use your associations by loading the user model.

```
@twitteruser = Twitteruser.find(session[:twitteruser_id])
@myserveys = @twitteruser.surveys
```